# .htaccess REQUEST_URI doesn't contain folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have site with 2 other sites in subfolders

```
https://example.com/    
https://example.com/demo1    
https://example.com/demo2
```

All 3 sites are actually wordpress installations.

The problem is: when I opened a page 
https://example.com/demo1/testpage

I got redirected to 
https://example.com/testpage

Contents of example.com/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried to add one more RewriteCond before RewriteRule (one line at a time):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !demo1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo1/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !demo1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/demo1/(.*)$
```

But none of this worked.

So how to make it work and avoid redirect?

Comment: What are the contents of your demo1 .htaccess? Does RewriteBase in there include /demo1?

Comment: Victoria, all 3 .htaccess files were the same. I've changed RewriteBase to /demo1 but still got redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange but solution was to resave site url in wordpress settings on /demo1/wp-admin/options-general.php